# How does the colorForth /mod algorithm work?

Tags: division, integer-division, forth, color-forth

I've been looking at [Chuck Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Moore)'s [colorForth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColorForth) recently, and I came upon this snippet of code (rendered in a traditional syntax):

```
: /mod for begin over over . + -if drop 2* [ swap ] next ; then over or or - 2* - next ;
```

With the following explanation:

> ```
>    Divide operation: trial subtract and shift in either 0 or 1
> ```

I'm really confused as to how this implements the full division operation.  I realize the `2*` shifts in a 0, the `- 2* -` shifts in a 1, and `over or or` implements a nip operation.  I also understand the mixed loops and if combo.

Here's where I am falling short.

1. It seems to be expecting two items on the stack, the numerator and the denominator, which makes sense.  However, the initial `for` pushes the TOS to the return stack, leaving only one item on the return stack.  The `over over` operation works with two values present however, so I'm not sure what is happening.
2. He mentions subtraction, but there is no inversion happening, except for the `- 2* -` branch, which is already mentioned as shifting in a 1.
3. I'm not sure how you can construct the quotient bit by bit by only shifting in 1s or 0s (into the divisor?).

Some thoughts:

1. Maybe it depends on the particular word size of the chip Chuck was programming and the rollover after adding enough times
2. Maybe there is a preamble missing that inverts the denominator, resulting in the subtraction that is mentioned on every loop.

Some idiosyncrasies between colorForth and other Forths:

- `.` is a nop for timing purposes on Chuck's chips.
- `-` is a bitwise inversion, rather than subtraction.
- `or` is exclusive or instead of inclusive or

For additional information, Here's the source:
[Description of function and use of colorForth opcodes](https://colorforth.github.io/inst.htm)

Comment: Not that I understand what this does, but looking at another page (https://colorforth.github.io/arith.htm), he gives an alternative definition where (i) the dividend is double-precision and (ii) the divisor is negative. So (i) would answer your first problem, and (ii) is basically what you have already conjectured.

Comment: ... although, looking at the other algorithm, maybe this version of `/mod` also has a third argument, which is the index of the highest bit (e.g. 17 for 18-bit words)

Comment: The chip was in standard PC hardware (x86), likely 32 bit. [1999 "Fireside chat"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1FUY6g5crA).

Comment: The colorForth part starts at [08 min 13 secs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1FUY6g5crA&t=8m13s).

Comment: There is [a transcript](http://www.ultratechnology.com/cm52299.htm).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just for reference: the [excellent answer](http://al.howardknight.net/?ID=160347509500) on this question was posted in comp.lang.forth by Ulrich Hoffmann.

---

Please edit this post to make it more detailed.

Comment: Perhaps better as a comment.

Comment: I suggest to put all information in one useful post by joint efforts. So I made this post a community wiki. Searching an answer in comments is not so convenient.