# How can I write my own colon definition in ColorForth?

Tags: forth, color-forth

How can I write my own colon definitions in ColorForth?

I tried to write `:` in interpretation mode, but it shows `:?`.

Do I need to change the entry colour in interpretation mode?

Do I need to use the editor? If so, on what block?

I entered my colon definition in block 300 (I found it empty), but I cannot execute it. Do I need to compile the block?

[image]

I found that I have to load the block with `ll`, and it works.

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Note: This is one of the exceptions where [a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) *** *** ***is*** *** *** acceptable (because it is ColorForth (the colours carry crucial information)).

Comment: Some references: [Chuck Moore (Forth) Fireside Chat - 1999-05-22 1999](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1FUY6g5crA&t=19m40s) (Introduces colorForth. The colorForth part starts at 19 min 40 secs. The audio is awful, but there is [a transcript](http://www.ultratechnology.com/cm52299.htm)), *[How does the colorForth /mod algorithm work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361082)*, and *[2022-06-25. Re-reimaging colorForth for the Web. Brad Nelson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvHfm_6Cbok)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In colorForth, the red word is a definition of a new Forth word, and there isn't any need to start with the ":" character. colorForth doesn't know the ":" word, and it displays "?" after any word not defined.

A newer version, of colorForth 4.2c (2011), a win32 version, but an old release now, it is at: https://www.greenarraychips.com/home/support/index.php#software

The same information about the colorForth 2001 version: https://colorforth.github.io/

There is a [NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler), cf2023 modified version, by Howerd Oakford at https://github.com/Howerd/colorForth.